# How can I apply VPC Firewall Rule to open the connection for only my IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I create a VPC firewall rule to restrict all connection except my public IP. Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Firewall Rule]

But I can't access to URL of VM instance after applying this Firewall Rule. Do you guys have another way to help me plz ?

Comment: What ports are you trying to access? What ports did you allow in your firewall rule?

Comment: Any port! Please skip the port.

Comment: So, select "allow all" for port and protocols.

Comment: Other question, do you try to access to your VM with which url? Did you try with the public IP? Do you have firewall restriction on your side? Did you test from cloud shell?

Comment: I resolved this issue. Thank you very much for your time.